# Scala Tutorial with Mysterious Variable

Tags: scala, variables, match

I'm new to Scala, and going through a tutorial about extractors (appy/unapply), and came across this simple example.  Could someone explain to me why this compiles and runs, when the variable “num” doesn’t seem to be defined anywhere?  It appears to only be valid inside the "match" statement.

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val x = Demo(5)
      println(x)

      x match {
         case Demo(num) => println(x+" is bigger two times than "+num)

         //unapply is invoked
         case _ => println("i cannot calculate")
      }
   }
   def apply(x: Int) = x*2
   def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2==0) Some(z/2) else None
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling object source code....
$scalac Demo.scala 2>&1

Executing the program....
$scala -classpath . Demo 
10
10 is bigger two times than 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `num` is *bound* by the pattern `case Demo(num) => ...`.

Its scope begins right after the `case Demo(num)` part, so you can use it in guard-expressions:

```
case Demo(num) if num % 42 == 0 => ...
```

and it ends either with the next `case`, or with the end of the `match`-block.

From the [spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html) (emphasis mine):

> Pattern matching tests whether a given value (or sequence of values)
>   has the shape defined by a pattern, and, if it does, **binds the**
>   **variables in the pattern** to the corresponding components of the value
>   (or sequence of values). The same variable name may not be bound more
>   than once in a pattern.

It's the same as with `(x: Int) => x * x` - the variable `x` is bound by the lambda, and can be used only in the body of the lambda. The only difference is that the left-hand sides before `=>` can have a much more interesting "shape" in `match-case` expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Andrey.  I guess I'm wondering how num was able to get the value 5.  I'm guessing the unapply() provided it, but then how did the z value in unapply() get bound to 10?

Comment: @HelotesEric That's the entire point of extractors. To get the easy stuff out of the way: `val x = Demo(5)` should be clear - it's just sets `x` to `Demo.apply(5)`, that is, `x = 10`. Then comes the part with the extractor. The `x match { case Demo(num) => ... }` attempts to invoke `Demo.unapply` on the value of `x`, that is, it invokes `Demo.unapply(10)`. Since 10 is even, the `unapply` method returns `Some(5)`. Because it returns a `Some` (and not `None`), the `case Demo(num) => ...` pattern does indeed match, and the variable `num` is bound to `5`.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the explanation!